# How can I add folders and files to a docker container running on ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

Assuming I have the following `docker-compose`

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  skyrimserver:
    container_name: skyrimserver
    image: tiltedphoques/st-reborn-server:latest
    ports:
      - "10578:10578/udp"
    volumes:
     - /opt/docker/skyrimserver/config:/home/server/config
     - /opt/docker/skyrimserver/logs:/home/server/logs
     - /opt/docker/skyrimserver/Data:/home/server/Data
    restart: unless-stopped
```

I would like to have the folders specified under `volumes` created & filled with some files before running it. It seems like the docker integration creates a `EFS file system` automatically which is empty. How can I hook into that to add files upon creation?

EDIT: A nice solution would be to have the ability to change the config on-the-fly and reloading within the game, not having to restart the whole server because the new docker file includes new configuration files

Comment: With one specific corner case that only applies to local native Docker and its named volume system, container systems never automatically copy files into volumes or mount points.  Your container's startup sequence needs to manage this itself, maybe in an entrypoint wrapper script.

Comment: @DavidMaze So I'd need to attach the persistent storage to EC2 before and know the name that this volume will have to bind it via volumes right?

Answer (score 1):

docker compose is a tool to define run docker. When you define volumes in yaml file it's similar to run docker with arg `--mount` and there is no volume in that instance for you to mount.

What you need with ECS is a fully functioning image with all sources of files in it, using a Dockerfile like this to build image might work:

```
FROM tiltedphoques/st-reborn-server

CP /opt/docker/skyrimserver/config /home/server/config
CP /opt/docker/skyrimserver/logs /home/server/logs
CP /opt/docker/skyrimserver/Data /home/server/Data

EXPOSE 10578
```

Edit: In case you still want to use ECS, you can try to [SSH to that container](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/instance-connect.html) or use [system manager to connect to container](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ec2-run-command.html) and put your file in `/home/server/`. I strongly AGAINST this method because EFS
is ridiculously slow without dump data.

You should change to use EBS backed EC2 instances. It's easy to scale with auto scaling group and suit your usecase

Comment: Smart idea, but this would force me to restart the whole container when any config changes. I'd like to change some properties and simply reload them while playing the game.

Comment: @Regyn That's the point of ECS. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Hi hope this would help just pu dot infront of you location:

version: "3.9"

services:
skyrimserver:

```
container_name: skyrimserver
image: tiltedphoques/st-reborn-server:latest
ports:
  - "10578:10578/udp"
volumes:
 - ./opt/docker/skyrimserver/config:/home/server/config
 - ./opt/docker/skyrimserver/logs:/home/server/logs
 - ./opt/docker/skyrimserver/Data:/home/server/Data
restart: unless-stopped
```